# UIPageViewController - changing dots won't work

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using a `UIPageViewController` to swipe between two ViewControllers. I tried to display indicator dots, which worked (see `addDots`). But somehow the dots will only change on next swipe, but not when I swipe to the previous view.

Can anybody tell me where I've made a mistake?

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class LeasingTutorialViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    var pageControl = UIPageControl()

    lazy var viewControllerList:[UIViewController] = {

        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vc1 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "leasingPageOne")
        let vc2 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "leasingPageTwo")

        return [vc1, vc2]
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self
        addDots()
        if let firstViewController = viewControllerList.first as? LeasingPageOneViewController {
            self.setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func addDots() {
        let color = UIColor(red: 24/255, green: 90/255, blue: 189/255, alpha: 1)

        pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 100,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 50))
        pageControl.numberOfPages = viewControllerList.count
        pageControl.currentPage = 0
        pageControl.tintColor = color
        pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = color
        self.view.addSubview(pageControl)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }

        let previousIndex = vcIndex - 1
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else { return nil }

        guard viewControllerList.count > previousIndex else { return nil }

        self.pageControl.currentPage = previousIndex

        return viewControllerList[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }

        let nextIndex = vcIndex + 1

        guard viewControllerList.count != nextIndex else { return nil }

        guard viewControllerList.count > nextIndex else { return nil }

        self.pageControl.currentPage = nextIndex

        return viewControllerList[nextIndex]
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share a demo of the problem ?

Comment: @sh_khan Two dots are correctly being displayed in the bottom. When I swipe to the right to the next view, the dot indicator changes as expected. Now if I swipe back to the previous view (to the left) - the dots won’t change again.

Comment: can't reproduce from your current code demo may help

Comment: @Tim to update `currentPage`-property you better use some of the `UIPageControllerDelegate` method.